# How to add OR AND into search results on Google Web Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on to a Google webapp Crud that searches from Google Sheets Data (by watching a YouTube Tutorial). I'm trying to work get multiple results on search.

E.g. When I search for **APPLE** the current code gives the results only the rows that contains Apple, when I search for **APPLE OR ORANGE** the results goes empty *(even though the table contains apples and oranges)*.

After multiple trying I failed to get my search results working,

```
function search(){

var searchinput = document.getElementById("searchinput").value.toString().toLowerCase().trim();
var searchWords = searchinput.split(/\s+/);
var searchColumns = [0,1,2,3,5,6];


var resultsArray = data.filter(function(r){
  return searchWords.every(function(word){
    return searchColumns.some(function(colIndex){
      return r[colIndex].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(word) !== -1
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: try to replace `...return searchWords.every(function(word)...` with `...return searchWords.some(function(word)...`

Comment: @Sergey it works but problem is the search is not accurate, because it's pulling data from multiple columns. Is there a way I can use a symbol something like "&" "|" "Or"  only to pick the data from them. e.g. Apple small & Orange big

Comment: Now the script takes your search phrase (e.g. APPLE OR ORANGE) and searches for the words (apple, or, orange) in columns 0,1,2,3,5,6. If any of the search words is found in any of these columns, the row with the data will be added to resultsArray. And how would you like to change this algorithm?

Comment: ok, The column 0 has the Ref number (No Need AND OR), Column 1 has the products name (Need to search Apple or Orange), Column 2 has the sizes ( need to search Big or small or medium) in Column 3 has the Location ( need to search New York or London Or Delhi) other columns can be ignored in search. E.g. want to search "Apple | Orange big London" can we get only the results for these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Filtering a 2D array based on multiple criteria

You want to filter an array, which I assume to look something like this:

```js
const data = [
  [12, "Apple", "small", "NewYork"],
  [11, "Orange", "big", "London"],
  [10, "Orange", "small", "Cairo"],
  [9, "Banana", "medium", "Paris"]
];
```

You want a search term to be entered in this format:

```
Apple | Orange big London
```

Which will then filter the rows if they contain "Apple" in any columns OR they contain "Orange" AND "big" AND "London". So the equivalent could also be written like this:

```
"Apple" | ("Orange" && "big" && "London")
```

#### Modified Script

```js
const data = [
  [12, "Apple", "small", "NewYork"],
  [11, "Orange", "big", "London"],
  [10, "Orange", "small", "Cairo"],
  [9, "Banana", "medium", "Paris"]
];

function search() {
  var searchinput = "Apple | Orange big London";
  // first split the "OR"
  var searches = searchinput.split("|");
  // Then for each serach "set", split again by " "
  searches = searches.map((s) => {
    var terms = s.trim().split(" ");
    return terms.map((t) => t.trim());
  });

  // Finally filter data 
  var results = data.filter((r) => {
    // Initializing this so that the scope is retained
    var shouldInclude = false;
    searches.forEach((terms) => {
      var results = terms.map((term) => r.includes(term)) // eg [true, true, true, false]
      if (results.every(r => r === true)) shouldInclude = true
    });
    return shouldInclude;
  });

  console.log(results);
  return results;
}

search();
```

#### Result

```
[
  [
    12,
    "Apple",
    "small",
    "NewYork"
  ],
  [
    11,
    "Orange",
    "big",
    "London"
  ]
]
```

This should also work for your test data, since it searches every column for a match.

#### Edit

If your search term at the beginning is "Oran" then it will not match "Orange". To have more flexible matching, you can update this portion of the code:

```js
// Finally filter data
var results = data.filter((r) => {
  // Initializing this so that the scope is retained
  var shouldInclude = false;
  var stringToSearch = r.join(" ");
  
  searches.forEach((terms) => {
    var results = terms.map(term => Boolean(stringToSearch.match(term))); // eg [true, true, true, false]
    if (results.every((r) => r === true)) shouldInclude = true;
  });
  return shouldInclude;
});
```

With this change a search like this:

```
App | Oran big Lond
```

Will return the same result.